# Downvote on 'legitmate' answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm curious, and would like to hear some opinion

How should I *see* on the down-vote on [this](https://superuser.com/a/966296/346288)?

It feels like the reader didn't **like** to hear what most certainly is the 'truth' about these devices.
I can understand that this might motivate it though.

Ref: https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Not meaning to be rude but the downvote may be because you are failing to note that their problem is not with the UPS itself (whose operation they accept and understand) but with the fact that problem is with the external battery as they have no way to know how much time it has remaining and whether they do actually need to shut down their systems.  If I knew I had a battery system that still had a good 5 minutes of supply at 10% then I would set the shutdown to happen at 10%, with no battery indication that is impossible to do.

Comment: I can only agree with that, and now we're wandering off from my question ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downvotes express **opinion**. Downvotes are:

- Anonymous. Not even moderators can find out who made the downvote.
- Not beholden to any explanation or further interaction between the person who dropped the downvote and the original poster.
- Not something you should worry or care about, unless you get a lot of them. Even great answers with hundreds of upvotes might have 10 downvotes, but that doesn't make them bad answers.
- Up to the individual casting the vote, as to whether they want to explain their reasoning or not.

A lot of downvotes might suggest to you that there's a problem with the quality of your question/answer, but one or two downvotes, especially if coupled with one or more upvotes, is nothing to worry about. It's not worth even discussing, because not only is it a minor thing, but you can easily outshine any downvotes you get with quality posts, because you get so much more rep from upvotes than you lose from downvotes.

Don't try to read into it. Don't speculate about their possible reasoning for doing it. **It doesn't matter.** Just move on.

Comment: always on the point, people take points like a smart contest or personal attack, but they are NOT, votes express an opinion and they are respectable even if they are negative.

Answer (score 5):

> How should I see on the down-vote on [this](https://superuser.com/a/966296/346288)?

What is the problem here? You posted an answer. You got exactly ***one*** downvote. And now you are coming to the Meta site to discuss what exactly?

You should see it as *one random user* stumbling across your answer and not liking it and that’s it. I’ve had tons of questions and answers that got an initial down-vote that then had a pile of up-votes. Get over it. And if there is a sudden flood of down-votes, you can always delete your answer and step back to try and better understand what went wrong.

Also if the original poster did not like your answer, they have a right to downvote it. And honestly if I look at the original question that was asked which clearly was/is, **“How do I know how much power is left on my external battery?”** Your answer does not provide an answer as to how to measure remaining power on a UPS battery.

That said, the question itself has some close votes because it’s honestly not a question appropriate for Super User. So your down-vote most likely comes from attempting to answer an inappropriate question with an answer that does not address the subject so in conclusion…

[image]

Comment: `You should see it as one random user stumbling across your answer and not liking it and that’s it. ` - ;-)  right, then I'm wrting text that is matching that random person more than once. Well. `an answer that does not address the subject so in conclusion` - and that is true, but anything else than that particular answer would be a lie in this case.

Comment: Right, I have no explicit reason to believe this *right now* though - even having experienced this to be the case at times. Let's stop there, I'll keep this in mind though.

Comment: That is a question of style; I believe the backticks enhance the readability - straight quotes are harder to discern whether they should be included (in example code for instance).  Is there a 'style guide' somewhere?

Comment: Note that the larger `backticked` area was a quote.

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=style - lots of reading, but no real 'guide'?

Comment: Right. I'll keep an eye on this, and read some of the discussion.